# The non-abstract class '_LoadingScreenState' is missing implementations

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an error:

> Compiler message: lib/screens/loading_screen.dart:10:7: Error: The
>   non-abstract class '_LoadingScreenState' is missing implementations
>   for these members:
>    - State.build Try to either
>    - provide an implementation,
>    - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
>    - mark the class as abstract, or
>    - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
>
> class _LoadingScreenState extends State {
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1314:10:
>   Context: 'State.build' is defined here.   Widget build(BuildContext
>   context);
>            ^^^^^
>
> I tried different things but they did not work. I updated my android
>   studio.
>
> Compiler message: lib/screens/loading_screen.dart:10:7: Error: The
>   non-abstract class '_LoadingScreenState' is missing implementations
>   for these members:
>    - State.build Try to either
>    - provide an implementation,
>    - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
>    - mark the class as abstract, or
>    - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
>
> class _LoadingScreenState extends State {
>         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart:1314:10:
>   Context: 'State.build' is defined here.   Widget build(BuildContext
>   context);

My Code:

```
import 'package:clima/screens/location.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  void getLocation() async {
    Location location = Location();

    await location.getCurrentLocation();
    print(location.latitude);
    print(location.longitude);
  }

  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
    print(response.statusCode); // Body or StatusCode

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      getData();
      return Scaffold();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `build` method is placed in the wrong place, in your code you have the following:

```
  void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
    print(response.statusCode); // Body or StatusCode

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      getData();
      return Scaffold();
    }
  }
```

Both the brackets for if and else are correct, while the brackets for the `getData()` is after the closing of the `build` method...

Change it to the following:

```
 void getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(
        "https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22");
    print(response.statusCode); // Body or StatusCode

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;
      print(data);
    } else {
      print(response.statusCode);
    }
  }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      getData();
      return Scaffold();
    }
```